# Alfresco authentication with OpenId

Tags: java, openid, alfresco

This is not supported by Alfresco out of the box, anyone with any ideas to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot is possible by coding, but you just need to know that Alfresco stores users internally. Even when using an Ldap. So there needs to be a user @ Alfresco's side.

So what you could do, is map the users and create a custom authentication system(subsystem).

In your Java code you could check if the user is succesfully authenticated with OpenId, then you could create a new internal Alfresco user and use the same username as the OpenId.

So the next time you can use the user from alfresco within.

The next question is how to manage/use/store the passwords......that's something what will need more investigation.